# Rendering to JS with Jinja produces invalid number rather than string

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I want to pass a string to some JavaScript in a template.  However, the string is being interpreted as an (invalid) number when the JavaScript runs.  How do I pass a string to a JavaScript variable?

```
@app.route('/loadNext')
def loadNext():
    return render_template('next.html', value='1.1.1.1')
```

```javascript
$("#loadtable").ready(
    function(){
     var tmp = {{ value }};
     alert(tmp);       
});
```

Comment: Assuming the output is correct, your code should work; http://jsfiddle.net/yhtxknk1/. I can only assume the `{{message.mac[0][0]}}` is not giving you the array in a JS-acceptable format. Have you checked what the format of the source looks like when it reaches the client?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that

```
{{ '1.1.1.1' }}
```

renders as

```
1.1.1.1
```

Quotes are not included. JavaScript tries to parse this as a number and can't. Fortunately, Flask includes a Jinja filter for this.

```
var tmp = {{ value|tojson }};
```

[`tojson`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters) will include quotes around strings and omit them for numeric values.  The filtered value, when rendered by Jinja, is valid JavaScript with the correct type.