# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & error for flask and html

Tags: python, html, encoding, flask

I am having simple flask application running with below code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test')
def getUsers():
    users = requests.get(get_users_url)
    return render_template("index.html", users=users.json())
```

And have `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
  <script> 
   var user = {{users}}
  </script>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

In html I am not able to access `{{users}}` value,it gives me an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

In `index.html` in script tag, it shows value for user like: `{&34#;users&#34:test}`

Comment: try this just pass `users` instead of `users.json`.

Comment: It's giving me HTTP response status i.e. 200 Ok. JS showing value as - &lt;Response [200]&gt

Comment: put the `users` in `h1` tag and check wether it prints the value or not.

Comment: Yes, it prints in h1 tag

Comment: then its working fine and http response also says succeeded.

Comment: Http response is JSON response. How can I access keys and values from JSON on html page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113312/discussion-between-rohitkadam19-and-shivsn).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering to JS with Jinja produces invalid number rather than string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344773/rendering-to-js-with-jinja-produces-invalid-number-rather-than-string)